# Publishing SWF that uses Flex SDK

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

When i test the flash application from inside the flash-cs4 it works fine, but when i try to export the movie, it gives an error:

`You have used a feature that requires the Flex SDK:
Embed metadata
Please set the Flex SDK path if necessary and add it to the library path for this file. The Flex SDK folder contains the bin, frameworks, lib and other folders.`

I check on the settings and in the library path i have an entry: ${FlexSDK}/frameworks/libs/flex.swf. What else do i have to do to make the exported swf work?

ps: I use the Embed meta-tag in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

target the Flex *.swc* file.  path example:

```
SDKs/flex_sdk/4.1.0/frameworks/libs/flex.swc
```

Comment: Downloaded the flex sdk from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download-all.html and there is no flex.swc

Comment: Turns out you need an older version. I tried 3.3A from http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Download%20Flex%203/ and that did the trick, although I had to give the flex_sdk_3.3.0.4852A directory and not the flex.swc itself.